# Array length returns 0 even if there are elements in it?

Tags: solidity, truffle, arrays

```
    pragma solidity >=0.8.13;

    contract MyContract {
    
    // ...Variables declared here
    
    constructor() {
            // ... Variables initialized here
        }
    
    address[] public myParticipants;
    
     function someFunction() public {
     myParticipants.push(msg.sender);
    
    }
}
```

***However, if I use truffle and call `myParticipants.length` it always returns me 0, even if `someFunction()` has been called a couple of times and addresses have been pushed into the array.
Why is that?***

Comment: In smart contract code that you shared, you did not declare the contract. Is it an oversight
or no?

Comment: It's just a question oversight, in the code it is declared. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @AndrewHoover898 How are you getting `myParticipants.length` in truffle?

Comment: >MyContract.deployed().then((instance) => { mc= instance; });
>mc.myParticipants.length

Answer (score 1):

you cannot acces to the length of the array because the getter function for myParticipants doesn't return the entire array and that is the reason why you can't access to the array length

from the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#getter-functions):

> If you have a public state variable of array type, then you can only retrieve single elements of the array via the generated getter function. This mechanism exists to avoid high gas costs when returning an entire array. You can use arguments to specify which individual element to return, for example data(0). If you want to return an entire array in one call, then you need to write a function, for example:

take a look at my answer to this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/128905/how-to-get-the-length-of-an-array-of-structs/128967#128967)